# How to reset the hotkeys and shortcuts in windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, hotkeys

Something went wrong in my windows 8, the windows button's stopped working and I can't live without <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>..etc.

Is there any way to reset this shortcuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very detailed tutorial. This tutorial works with the `English-language-keyboard`. But of course you can change it, to every language you want:

That should reset your keystrokes.

> 1. Move the mouse pointer to the bottom right corner of the screen. This will bring out the side menu. Click on “Settings”. Select
>      “Control Panel” from the following menu. An alternative method is to
>      press “Win” key together with the “R” key. Select “Control Panel” from
>      this menu.
> 2. Select “Add a language” in the “Control Panel” window. You will find this link in the “Clock, Language and Region” section of the
>      panel. If you have the layout of the Control Panel set to “Small
>      icons” this option will appear as “Language” in the alphabetical list
>      of functions.
> 3. Read the list of languages shown as active on the computer. It is better to only have one, and that should be shown as a box which has
>      English (United Kingdom) written inside it. If you don’t have that,
>      click on the “Add a language” tab at the top of the language list.
> 4. Choose the “English” box in the list of languages that are displayed in the next screen. Find the “English (United Kingdom)” box
>      in the next list. You will be returned to the “Change your language
>      preferences” screen and a box saying “English (United Kingdom)” should
>      have been added to the page. There is less possibility of the keyboard
>      being reset back to an unwanted version if this box is the only
>      language available. If you don’t need to switch to other languages on
>      your computer, remove all other languages from this page. The “English
>      (United Kingdom)” box should be the first in the list.

[Source](http://www.ehow.co.uk/how_12260934_reset-keys-keyboard-windows-8.html)

Comment: Where i can find that Tools?

Comment: I've added a much more detailed one. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But unfortunately it did nothing to the Windows button, i have also tried to use another keyboard but I still have the same problem.

Comment: It's very trivial, but are you using a gaming-keyboard? Because there is a switch with this you can disable the windows-key. It has the logo of a joystick on it.

Comment: No it's a standard keyboard on HP laptop, It was working, but it seems that a software have changed my registry, the key as a hardware is working, but i need to reset it to its original state.

Comment: I'm sorry. This is the only possiblity that I know.

Comment: Doing this method with “English (United States) worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can remap the keys by playing with the registry but its extremely complex and can mess up things - I would recommend third party tool

Sharp Keys  is the best tool for remapping windows key to some other key( of your choice) however you must not remap important and frequently used keys - You can remap alt or ctrl key for your windows key, totally your choice ,

[Here is a link](http://www.programmerfish.com/customize-keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-8-using-sharpkeys/) which gives perfect step by step screen shots to use and remap the keys using this tool

Download this tool here :  http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/#

Comment: which Tools you mean?

Comment: check now and use this tool, and let me know if it works

Comment: It didn't take effect on Windows 8!